How to change the font size in footnote citation when using metropolis theme in beamer
I'm using the metropolis theme in beamer and want to use the command \footfullcite of package biblatex to generate references in the footnote.
I want to use the font size \tiny of the references in the footnote. The font size of normal footnotes has successfully changed, but it ceases to work for the references generated by \footfullcite.
When using Warsaw theme, it can be achieved. I do not know why switching to metropolis theme would render the font size ineffective. Is there any methods to achieve it?
The following is the MWE, and some codes are borrowed from Add square brackets to footfullcite in beamer.
\begin{filecontents*}{References.bib}
@article{ahlswede2000network,
    title={Network information flow},
    author={Ahlswede, Rudolf and Cai, Ning and Li, Shuo-Yen Robert and Yeung, Raymond W},
    journal={Information Theory, IEEE Transactions on},
    volume={46},
    number={4},
    pages={1204--1216},
    year={2000},
    publisher={IEEE}
}
@article{katti2008xors,
    title={{XORs in the air: practical wireless network coding}},
    author={Katti, Sachin and Rahul, Hariharan and Hu, Wenjun and Katabi, Dina and M{\'e}dard, Muriel and Crowcroft, Jon},
    journal={IEEE/ACM Transactions on Networking (ToN)},
    volume={16},
    number={3},
    pages={497--510},
    year={2008},
    publisher={IEEE Press}
}
\end{filecontents*}

%%% 

\documentclass[t, 11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle, numbering=fraction]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
    \parindent 0em\noindent%
    \raggedright
    \usebeamercolor{footnote}\hbox to 0.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\tiny\insertfootnotetext}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{family=\sffamily,size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{footnote mark}{family=\sffamily,size=\tiny}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{References}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{\tiny\hbox{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}\usebeamerfont*{footnote mark}[\@thefnmark]}}}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\tiny{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}\usebeamerfont*{footnote mark}[\@thefnmark]}\enspace\usebeamerfont*{footnote}\tiny #1}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[c]{XOR network coding}
        XOR network coding \footfullcite{ahlswede2000network} \footfullcite{katti2008xors}
    
        This is a normal footnote \footnote{here is a footnote}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}



Use the moloch theme. It is an updated fork of the metropolis theme and, amongst many other improvements, doesn't hard code the font size for bib items:
\documentclass[t, 11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle, numbering=fraction]{moloch}
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
    \parindent 0em\noindent%
    \raggedright
    \usebeamercolor{footnote}\hbox to 0.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\tiny\insertfootnotetext}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{family=\sffamily,size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{footnote mark}{family=\sffamily,size=\tiny}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{References.bib}
@article{ahlswede2000network,
    title={Network information flow},
    author={Ahlswede, Rudolf and Cai, Ning and Li, Shuo-Yen Robert and Yeung, Raymond W},
    journal={Information Theory, IEEE Transactions on},
    volume={46},
    number={4},
    pages={1204--1216},
    year={2000},
    publisher={IEEE}
}
@article{katti2008xors,
    title={{XORs in the air: practical wireless network coding}},
    author={Katti, Sachin and Rahul, Hariharan and Hu, Wenjun and Katabi, Dina and M{\'e}dard, Muriel and Crowcroft, Jon},
    journal={IEEE/ACM Transactions on Networking (ToN)},
    volume={16},
    number={3},
    pages={497--510},
    year={2008},
    publisher={IEEE Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{\tiny\hbox{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}\usebeamerfont*{footnote mark}[\@thefnmark]}}}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\tiny{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}\usebeamerfont*{footnote mark}[\@thefnmark]}\enspace\usebeamerfont*{footnote}\tiny #1}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[c]{XOR network coding}
        XOR network coding \footfullcite{ahlswede2000network} \footfullcite{katti2008xors}
    
        This is a normal footnote \footnote{here is a footnote}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}



It's a very nice idea!
